# In google Calendar api, is it possible to retrieve the most recent events?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am currently working with google calendar api in nodejs platform and trying to get the last 1000 events. 
There is the min and max parameters but if I put today as maxTime then I get the first 1000 events (from 2013) instead of the most recent.
Does anyone have any idea how to implement this in nodejs? 
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The parameter [`timeMax`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#timeMax) is a datetime for an event's end time to filter by. Meaning, if you only use this parameter, you will get all the events in your calendar until you reach the date you specified in your `timeMax`.

The true purpose of this `timeMax` and `timeMin` is to filter the calendar events you specified in this both datetime.

For example, you use `timeMax` is **2016-12-30T00:00:00Z** and `timeMin` is **2016-12-01T00:00:00Z**, so the results are the calendar events from **Dec 1, 2016 up to Dec 30, 2016** in your calendar.

> Note: The datetime must be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time
>   zone offset, e.g., 2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00, 2011-06-03T10:00:00Z.
>   Milliseconds may be provided but will be ignored.

Comment: hi, I understand these parameters, the problem is that if we are in december 30th, and I want only the most recent 20 events, (let's say they all happened in the 29th and the 28th), I will get the first 20 events since december 1, and not descending. I need to know that the events that I'm getting back are the from today backward, and not from the lower bound (timeMin) till today...